# User properties for non Apps Script add-ons

Tags: google-workspace-add-ons

When developing an Workspace add-ons using Apps Script, I can use the PropertiesService and set/get properties (key/value) for each user. Is it possible to access the PropertiesService when using another language than Apps Script?

I have been searching for a REST/gRPC API interface for PropertiesService, but have not found anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

You could read more about [Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) that also works in key-value stores (or key value pairs, similar to the Script Properties in Google Apps Script)

> Storage objects are simple key-value stores, similar to objects, but they stay intact through page loads. The keys and the values are always strings (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings). You can access these values like an object, or with the Storage.getItem() and Storage.setItem() methods.

For other client-side storage methods, you can check out this [reference link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage#storing_simple_data_%E2%80%94_web_storage).

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and you have some good solutions, but as far as I understand you have to use JavaScript in the browser to use them. Unfortunately I don't think I have access to insert JavaScript into the Workspace Add-ons when I am using other runtimes than Apps Script. Please correct me if I am wrong.